# Custom font set up for android

Tags: android, android-activity, typeface, android-fonts

Can anyone help to point out the error in this code? it says run time error in DDMS. As a totally newbie in this programming, i'm not being able to find the mistake. I used this tutorial http://www.botskool.com/geeks/how-use-external-fonts-android and i implemented on only Mainactivity.java

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
...

        Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                "Dream of me.ttf");

        selectedTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.main_selected_textView);

        s=((CircleImageView) circleMenu
                .getSelectedItem()).getName();
        selectedTextView.setTypeface(typeface, 12);
        selectedTextView.setText(s);

    }
```

Comment: Are spaces allowed in resource names?

Comment: changed font name; but did not work. Added fonts folder under assets as well but same error

Comment: Solved it anyway. I was using an incompatible font.